# Wp-admin loguts me. When sign with Wp_singon

Tags: wp-admin, ssl

I made ajax login. It works fine. I can login the site. But when i try to access wp-admin it logouts me. I have to sign again in wp-login page. Here is my code:

```
function ajax_login() {

    check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-nonce', 'security');

    $info                  = array();
    $info['user_login']    = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember']      = true;

    $user = wp_signon($info, false);

    if (is_wp_error($user)) {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => __('Wrong password or Username')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => true, 'message' => __('You are signed in!')));
    }

    die();
}
```

I think it is about with ssl. Because i don't have this error in non ssl sites.

Comment: You mentioned an SSL. Are the front *and* back end both on HTTPS?

Comment: Yes both of is ssl